# Mock or override static method to test a class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, static-methods, powermock

I'm doing some unit test but I'm having problems trying to test a class. I have a class with a static builder method which returns the class instance:

```
public class MessageCaller {

 public static MessageCaller builder() {
    return new MessageCaller();
 }
 
 //Other methods
 
  public String publish() {
  //publishing to some Messages
  return "something";
  }
  
  public MessageCaller withAttribute(String key, String value) {
   //Some code
   return this;
  }
  
}

public class MessageCallerExtended extends MessageCaller {
  private Map<String, String> attributes;

  @Override
  public MessageCaller withAttribute(String key, String value) {
    if (this.attributes == null) {
      this.attributes = new HashMap();
    }

    this.attributes.put(key, value);
    return this;
  }

 //It's not working  because it's calling the base class builder and is not possible to be Overriten 
  //because it's a static method.
  public static MessageCallerExtended builder() {
    return new MessageCallerExtended();
  }

  @Override
  public String publish() {
    return "test";
  }

}
```

This is the method which I would like to test, the problem is that is calling the real publish method taking some time to finalize.

```
public void sendMessages(@Nonnull String group, @Nonnull String state) {

    this.message.builder()
        .toTopic(xxxx)
        .withAttribute(xxx, xxx)
        .withAttribute(xxx, xxx)
        .withAttribute(xxx,xxx)
        .publish();
}
```

I'm sending the message object in the constructor of the class.

I've created a Wrapper class to use in the unit test but the problem is that the builder method is static and for that reason is not possible to `@Override`, if I don't use the `@Override` tag I'll invoke the real builder method and then the real publish method and it is taking too much time to be processed, causing some problems, because is invoked for several unit test.

With **Mockito** I having similar issues with the static builder method, in fact it's not possible to mock static methods with **Mockito**. I'm not allowed to use another library like **PowerMock** for instance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add more code, with the test itself AND the code you're trying to test (like the code that is calling `builder()`

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I added more information to the question.

Comment: I don't really understand exactly what you're trying to test tbh. Why don't you use the real implementation directly? Also, You didn't include your test code with the assertions, this would provide more context

Comment: I'm trying to test the sendMessages method, the real problem is with the builder method because it is static and I don't know how can I test it without external libraries.